# FuelPHPのModelの階層化について

Tags: php, fuelphp, model-view-controller, orm

FuelPHPで開発をしているのですが、下のようなDBがあります。

```
userテーブル
id, service, service_id
```

---

```
deliveryテーブル
id, ...

saleテーブル
id, ...
```

userテーブルのserviceカラムには'delivery'や'sale'の文字列が入り、
service_idと各サービスのテーブルのidと紐づいています。

ここで質問なのですが、これらのテーブルに該当するModelはModel_Softを継承しています。
deliveryテーブルとsaleテーブルのようなserviceに該当するテーブルのみの
共通処理を書きたい場合、
serviceと言うModelを作成し、serviceモデルがModel_Softを継承し
さらにserviceモデルをdeliveryやsaleが継承し、共通処理をserviceに書くと言うやり方は
FuelPHPやFW的に考えた場合正しい設計になっていますでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FW的に言うと、継承を使うこと自体に問題はありません
継承利用時一般にいえる注意として、LSPだけ気を付けた方がよいです
なお、

- 子で共通の$_propertiesや$_observersをserviceに入れたい
- かつ子は子で独自の$_propertiesや$_observersを追加で持ちたい

といった場合、_init()でオートロード時にserviceとその子のプロパティをマージするといった工夫は必要となります